# Android Video Streaming Using DatagramSocket setPreviewCallback

Tags: c#, android, sockets, datagram

I've made an application that obeys UDP using Datagram Socket in android. I'm trying to use Camera's setPreviewCallback function to send bytes to a (c#) client, using Datagram Socket;

But,

The problem is : it throws an exception "The datagram was too big to fit the specified buffer,so truncated" and no bytes are received on client.

I've changed the size of buffer to different values but none work. Now :

Is Datagram approach is right?

What alternatives/approach I'd use to achieve the task?

What's the ideal solution for this?

Android Server :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start);
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    setTitle(GetCurrentIP());
    mainList = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
    secondaryList = new LinkedList<byte[]>();
    mCam = null;
    mCam = Camera.open();
    if (mCam == null) {
        Msg("Camera is null");
    } else {
        if (!Bind()) {
            Msg("Bind Error.");
        } else {
            Msg("Bound Success.");

            start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        mCam.setPreviewDisplay(videoView.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        Msg(e1.getMessage());
                    }
                    mCam.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            DatagramPacket pack;
                            try {
pack = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, InetAddress.getByName(clientIP), clientPort);
                                    me.send(pack);
                                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Msg(e.getMessage());
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Msg(e.getMessage());
                                }   
                            }
                        });
                        mCam.startPreview();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

private boolean Bind(){
    try {
        me = new DatagramSocket(MY_PORT);
        return true;
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Msg(e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}

private String GetCurrentIP(){
    WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    return Formatter.formatIpAddress(wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
}

public void Msg(String msg){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.v(">>>>>", msg);
}
}
```

C# client :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
      const int MY_PORT = 55566;
      IPAddress MY_IP;

      Thread Receiver;

      Socket me;
      EndPoint myEndPoint;

      EndPoint serverEndPoint;

      byte[] buffer;

      public Form1()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
      }

      private IPAddress GetCurrentIPAddress()
      {
           IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
           var selectedIPs = from ip in ips
                             where ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork
                             select ip;
           return selectedIPs.First();
      }

      private bool Bind()
      {
           try
           {
                myEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(MY_IP, MY_PORT);
                me.Bind(myEndPoint);
                return true;
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }

           return false;
      }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           try
           {
                MY_IP = GetCurrentIPAddress();
                this.Text = MY_IP.ToString()+":"+MY_PORT;

                me = new Socket
                (
                     AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                     SocketType.Dgram,
                     ProtocolType.Udp
                );


                if (!Bind())
                     Task.Run(()=> MessageBox.Show("Bind() error."));
                else
                     Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("Bind success."));
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
      }

      //private void AddToListBox(String msg)
      //{
      //     this.Invoke((Action)delegate() { this.listBox1.Items.Add((this.listBox1.Items.Count+1)+" : "+msg); });
      //}

      private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
           serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBoxmyIP.Text), int.Parse(textBoxmyPort.Text));
           Receiver = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Receive));
           Receiver.Start();
      }

      private Image ByteToImage(byte[] bytes)
      {
           MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
           return Image.FromStream(ms);
      }

      private void Receive()
      {
           while (true)
           {
                buffer = new byte[100];
                int nobs = me.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref serverEndPoint);
                if (nobs>0)
                {
                     Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("Bytes received"));
                     //AddToListBox(Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer));
                     //AddToPictureBox(buffer);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
           }
      }

      private void AddToPictureBox(byte[] buffer)
      {
           this.BeginInvoke
           (
                (Action)
                delegate()
                {
                     pictureBox1.Image = ByteToImage(buffer);
                }
           );
      }
 }
```

Comment: 100 bytes is ridiculously small for a video datagram buffer. Try 65500 and see if it works.  If that is too small, you're pretty well stuft with straightforward UDP.  Amyway, note that video streaming without a considerable amount of buffering and a good protocol is unlikely to work in any satisfactory manner.